# Unable to find and execute python script in shell

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix, privileges

I'm attempting to test a python script I wrote but when I attempt to run it with this command:

```
./simpletax.py
```

I get the following message:

```
: No such file or directory
```

I believe it is a permission thing since if I remove the execute privileges for the user I get the permission denied message but when I add the x back in I get the above message.

Here is the output of `ls -al`

```
 total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Apr 11 21:51 .
drwxr-x--- 3 user1 user2 4096 Apr  7 20:55 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user1 user1  620 Apr  7 21:57 hello.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user1 user1 2591 Apr 11 21:08 simpletax.py
```

As you can see the program I'm attempting to run (simpletax.py) has the same permissions as hello.py which runs just fine. I tried adding full rwx privileges for everyone but got the same error.

I'm really baffled at this point what I'm doing wrong, any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Can you run using `python3 simpletax.py`? - It's definitely not a permission issue though.

Comment: Yes, I can. I runs fine with that.

Comment: Try using `dos2unix sympletax.py`. It looks like your script has Windows CRLF line endings.

Comment: @Rostro Show us the first line of the file.

Comment: Can you find it using tab completion?

Comment: @ShellFish yes tab completion works. @jakekimds it's the same as hello.py `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: Huh, this is really strange. Try `cp simpletax.py test.py; chmod +x test.py; ./test.py`. Just curious at this point.

Comment: @Barmar That is what it was! Post as an answer and I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: No need to post an answer, it's already answered in that other question. Which I guess you would have found if you bothered to search for the error message.